# How to create a pivot query for single mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have create one table please refer below screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQY1i.png

But I have get result like below screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLrlk.png

I have use MYSQL and i want to use pivot in my sql query.

Please anyone can help me for this.

Thanks & Regards

Meet Bhatt

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I return pivot table output in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql)

Comment: MySQL doesn't support `pivot`.  Even if it did, I wouldn't recommend using it (why bother when other SQL constructs are just as simple?).